# Using capybara to select a bootstrap radio button

Tags: html, rspec, capybara

I have a set of radio buttons using bootstrap and want to use Capybara to select them using either id or value. For my rspec tests. For some reason it's not seeing the radio buttons and I wonder if anyone can have a look and suggest something.

Error I'm getting is

> Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find visible radio button "paper" that is not disabled
>   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find visible radio button "#paper" that is not disabled

HTML`

```
        </label>
        <label for="paper" id="paper" class="btn btn-primary choice col-lg-4 col-md-4">
          <input type="radio" value = "paper" name="rps" id="paper">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid image-responsive" src="/img/paper.png" alt="Paper">
          </input>

        </label>
        <label for="scissors" class="btn btn-primary choice col-lg-4 col-md-4">
          <input type="radio" value = "scissors" name="rps" id="scissors">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid image-responsive" src="/img/scissors.png" alt="Scissors">
          </input>

        </label>
      </div>`
```

TEST

```
 feature 'Testing if we divert to /result chosing an option and play' do
  scenario 'Choose option and click play' do
    sign_in_and_play
    click_button('Play')
    choose("#paper")
    # choose("paper")
    expect(page).to have_content("Result displayed here")
  end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Capybara is telling you it can't find the radio buttons because they aren't actually visible on the page.  Most likely, if you inspect the page you'll see that bootstrap is hiding the actual radio buttons (probably with `visibility: hidden` CSS) and replacing them with images so the styling is consistent across browsers.  One solution to this is to allow Capybara to click on the `label` rather than needing to click specifically on the radio button:

```
choose('scissors', allow_label_click: true)
```

You can also default to allowing `label` clicks by setting `Capybara.automatic_label_click = true`

Note: your sample HTML is illegal since both the paper `label` and `input` have `id="paper"` - I'm assuming that is meant to be like the "scissors" option where the `id` is only on the input.

Comment: Thank you. label wasn't supposed to have id, I was playing around to get it clicked. Thanks for pointing that out.
As far as the original issue is concerned, it's still the same, still getting the same error telling me it can't find the radio button 'scissors'.

Comment: It's actually still trying to click the radio button which his obviously hidden for styling.
I have tried giving label a unique id and tested with
find('#paper_label').click 
and that doesn't work either
Get error: Unable to find visible css "#paper_label"

Another thing I've tried was 
find('[for=paper]').click
Got error: Unable to find visible css "[for=paper]"

not sure if there's anything else I can try

Comment: @IDurrani What is the actual HTML while the page is live in a browser, and do you really mean for the img to be inside the input or should the input be closed and the img be a sibling included in the label?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Yeah well since i'm at early stage or all this, I thought it was a good idea. HTML after page loaded is below.

 <label for="rock" id="rock_label" class="btn btn-primary choice col-lg-4 col-md-4 active">
    <input type="radio" value = 'rock' name="rps" id="rock" checked>
         <img class="card-img-top img-fluid image-responsive" src="/img/rock.png" alt="Rock">
     </input>
</label>

Comment: Ok just realised that one of my </div> was commented out somehow. Uncommenting that fixed it.
Thank you so much.

Comment: `Capybara.automatic_label_click = true` was all to get my system tests to pass again, thanks!